# Why should I avoid using CGI?

Tags: ruby, cgi, fastcgi

I was trying to create my website using CGI and ERB, but when I search on the web, I see people saying I should always avoid using `CGI`, and  always use `Rack`.

I understand CGI will fork a lot of Ruby processes, but if I use `FastCGI`, only one persistent process will be created, and it is adopted by PHP websites too. Plus `FastCGI` interface only create one object for one request and has very good performance, as opposed to Rack which creates 7 objects at once.

Is there any specific reason I should not use CGI? Or it is just false assumption and it is entirely ok to use CGI/FastCGI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI, by which I mean both the interface and the common programming libraries and practices around it, was written in a different time.  It has a view of request handlers as distinct processes connected to the webserver via environment variables and standard I/O streams.

This was state-of-the-art in its day, when there were not really "web frameworks" and "embedded server modules" as we think of them today.  Thus...

## CGI tends to be slow

Again, the CGI model spawns one new process per connection.  While spawning processes *per se* is cheap these days, heavy web app initialization — reading and parsing scores of modules, making database connections, etc. — makes this quite expensive.

## CGI tends toward too-low-level (IMHO) design

Again, the CGI model explicitly mentions environment variables and standard input as the interface between request and handler.  But ... who cares?  That's much lower level than the app designer should generally be thinking about.  If you look at libraries and code based on CGI, you'll see that the bulk of it encourages "business logic" right alongside form parsing and HTML generation, which is now widely seen as a dangerous mixing of concerns.

Contrast with something like Rack::Builder, where right away the coder is thinking of mapping a namespace to an action, and what that means for the broader web application.  (Suddenly we are free to argue about the semantic web and the virtues of REST and this and that, because we're not thinking about generating radio buttons based off user-supplied input.)

Yes, something like Rack::Builder could be implemented on top of CGI, but, that's the point.  It'd have to be a layer of abstraction built *on top of CGI*.

## CGI tends to be sneeringly dismissed

Despite CGI working perfectly well within its limitations, despite it being simple and widely understood, CGI is often dismissed out of hand.  You, too, might be dismissed out of hand if CGI is all you know.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a lot of confusion about what CGI, Rack etc. really are. As I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009386/are-rack-based-web-servers-represent-fastcgi-protocol/33538573#33538573), Rack is an API, and FastCGI is a protocol. CGI is also a protocol, but in its narrow sense also an implementation, and for what you're speaking of is not at all the same thing as FastCGI. So let's start with the background.

Back in the early 90s, web servers simply read files (HTML, images, whatever) off the disk and sent them to the client. People started to want to do some processing at the time of the request, and the early solution that came out was to run a program that would produce the result sent back to the client, rather than just reading the file. The "protocol" for this was for the web server to be given a URL that it was configured to execute as a program (e.g., `/cgi-bin/my-script`), where the web server would then set up a set of environment variables with various information about the request and run the program with the body of the request on the standard input. This was referred to as the "[Common Gateway Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)."

Given that this forks off a new process for every request, it's clearly inefficient, and you almost certainly don't want to use this style of dynamic request handling on high-volume web sites. (Starting a whole new process is relatively expensive in computational resources.)

One solution to making this more efficient is to, rather than starting a new process, send the request information to an existing process that's already running. This is what FastCGI is all about; it maintains a very similar interface to CGI (you have a set of variables with most of the request information, and a stream of data for the body of the request). But instead of setting actual Unix environment variables and starting a new process with the body on `stdin`, it sends a request similar to an HTTP request to an FCGI server already running on the machine where it specifies the values of these variables and the request body contents.

If the web server can have the program code embedded in it somehow, this becomes even more efficient because it just runs the code itself. Two classic examples of how you might do this would be:

- Have PHP embedded in Apache, so that the "Apache server code" just calls the "PHP server code" that's part of the same process; and
- Not run Apache at all, but have the web server be written in Ruby (or Python, or whatever) and load and run more Ruby code that's been custom-written to handle the request.

So where does Rack come in to this? Rack is an **API** that lets code that handles web requests receive it in a common way, regardless of the web server. So given some Ruby code to process a request that uses the Rack API, the web server might:

- Be a Ruby web server that simply makes function calls in its own process to the Rack-compliant code that it loaded;
- Be a web server (written in any language) that uses the FastCGI protocol to talk to another process with FastCGI server code that, again, makes function calls to the Rack-compliant code that handles the request; or
- Be a server that starts a brand new process that interprets the CGI environment variables and standard input passed to it and then calls the Rack-compliant code.

So whether you're using CGI, FastCGI, another inter-process protocol, or an intra-process protocol, makes no difference; you can do any of those using Rack so long as the server knows about it or is talking to a process that can understand CGI, FastCGI or whatever and call Rack-compliant code based on that request.

So:

For performance scaling, you definitely don't want to be using CGI; you want to be using FastCGI, a similar protocol (such as the Tomcat one), or direct in-process calling of the code.

If you use the Rack API, you don't need to worry at the early stages which protocol you're using between your web server and your program because the whole point of APIs like Rack is that you can change it later.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CGI. Please. It's not worth it. Back in the 1990s when nobody knew better it seemed like a good idea, but that was when scripts were infrequent, used for special cases like handling form submissions, not driving entire sites.

FastCGI is an attempt at a "better CGI" but it's still deficient in a large number of ways, especially because you have to manage your FastCGI worker processes.

Rack is a much better system, and it works very well. If you use Rack, you have a wide variety of hosting systems to choose from, even [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) which is really simple and reliable.

I don't know what mean when you say Rack creates "7 objects at once" unless you mean there are 7 different Rack processes running somehow or you've made a mistake in your implementation.

I can't think of a single instance where CGI would be better than a Rack equivalent.

Comment: +1 Good answer, but is rack + Passenger really simpler than cgi? It seems to me that if you are using apache, cgi is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: It really does not get any simpler than Rack + Passenger. You create a `VirtualHost` entry, you have a `config.ru` file, and you're basically done. It'll start up when required and perform *very* fast when running. Why are you so attached to using CGI? It's one of the least efficient ways to handle this sort of thing. It's like asking "Why does everyone say to use USB drives? What's wrong with a floppy disk?"